# Establishing a "post ID" value for a comment leaving system

Tags: php, html, comments

I am trying to attach a numerical "post ID" value to comments so that they can be retrieved from the database and displayed in the proper place. How do I establish this numerical value within my html form as something that gets sent to the script that inserts it into the database? I assume I need to use GET or POST but I don't understand how to use those to send anything except text entered by the user.

This is the form I am using to send the "name" and "comment" inputs:

```
 <div class="comments">
 <form action="foxpost.php" method="post">

 <label for="name">Name</label><br>
 <input id="name" name="name" type="text" /><br>
 <label for="message">Comment</label><br>
 <textarea class="message" id="message" name="message"></textarea><br><br>

 <input type="Submit" value="Post Comment" />
 </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this question with PHP, I'm guessing thats the language your using for your back-end.  Another assumption I'm making is that your actually formatting your request querystring with the postID, something like "http://example.com/posts.php?postID=1212", notice the postID in the querystring, you just pass that on, like this:

```
 <div class="comments">
 <form action="foxpost.php?postID=<%= $_GET['postID'] %>" method="post">

 <label for="name">Name</label><br>
 <input id="name" name="name" type="text" /><br>
 <label for="message">Comment</label><br>
 <textarea class="message" id="message" name="message"></textarea><br><br>

 <input type="Submit" value="Post Comment" />
 </form>
 </div>
```

Using

```
<%= $_GET['postID'] %>
```

will simply echo the postID from the querystring straight into the HTML, or you could assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mysql you don't need to create it, mysql can auto-create it when you insert a new post.

For example we could create a table

```
CREATE TABLE `student` ( 
`student_id` INT( 3 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`name` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL , 
`email` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL , 
UNIQUE ( `student_id` ) 
);
```

And then use the following query

```
INSERT INTO `student` ( `name` , `email` ) VALUES ( 'john', 'email' );
```

As you can see the id is not specified in the query, but the field has the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. When you insert a student without an id it will get the highest id and add one. So if you have the empty table and run the above insert query, you will get 3 rows with id 1,2 and 3.

More in the mysql manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

p.s. if you are using a different database please specify wich one.

--- EDIT 1 ---
might have misread the question very badly (it's past midnight but that's not an excuse)
You have a few options if you want to pass
1. a hiddent field, that was mention here
2. a $_GET['postid'] from something like comment.php?postid=13 if you add comments from another page
3. both

BUT don't forget, before adding the comment that the post exists.

... might i suggest using the akismet library to cut down on spam ?
http://www.achingbrain.net/stuff/php/akismet

You can get a key for free when you register at wordpress.com

Comment: If you're using MySQL it would be the mysql_insert_id() function, called right after the INSERT statement as outlined by @vlad above...

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Thank you Don, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Put the id in a hidden field in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="id_goes_here" />
```

Comment: @Jimmy: Just keep in mind that, although the field is hidden, users *can* change the value of hidden fields using tools such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: That is insecure. If you want to generate the id from php you should do it before sending the sql, when you parse the comment from $_POST and dinamically create a value, without exposing it to the browser.

Comment: The OP wants to pass the ID of the post, that the user is commenting on, back to the server, so that the comment can be stored with a reference to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not have the ID as part of the form and just use your databases `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature.